# Telling when a Google Maps circle object has moved before making it visible

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

**Problem**

My segment works like this.  When I drag the map around (Google Maps Javascript API), I want a circle rendered at map centre to disappear.  When the dragging is done, I want the circle to move to the new centre **BEFORE** becoming visible again.

What ends up happening is that the circle becomes visible and then jerks over to the new position, even though I have them one before the other (set position, then change the visibility.)

**Attempt**

Here is the code that I was using for this segment:

```
control.getCircle().setCenter(latLng(latitude, longitude));
control.getCircle().setVisible(true);
```

Where latLng is a wrapper function I made to get LatLng object and control is the control object from angular-google-maps.

Even though setCenter is first, the circle still becomes visible before it is moved.  Is there anything I can do about this?  I have tried to wrap it in a promise, callbacks, etc. but nothing seems to do the trick.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with listeners on event  `center_changed` , event  `idle`  or event `dragstart`

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'center_changed', function() {
    control.getCircle().setCenter(latLng(latitude, longitude));
});

google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'dragstart', function() {
    control.getCircle().setVisible(false);
});

google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'idle', function() {
    control.getCircle().setVisible(true);
});
```